# Grouping elements in list by equivalence class

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, set

I have an issue when trying to make new lists from one list by applying sets.

Suppose I have the following list:

```
L=[[(a),(b),(c)],[(b),(c),(a)],[(a),(c),(b)],[(a),(d),(b)]]
```

And I wish to just creat ONE list from the lists in L which have the same elements. We can clearly see that:

```
[(a),(b),(c)], [(b),(c),(a)] and [(a),(c),(b)]
```

when seen as sets, they are the same, because all share the elements (a), (b) and (c).

So if I wish to create new lists from L applying this rule:

I would then need two new lists, which are:

```
[(a),(b),(c)] and [(a),(d),(b)]
```

since

```
[(a),(d),(b)]
```

seen as a set differs from the rest of the lists.

What would be an optimal way to do this? I know how to convert an element inside L as a set, but if I wish to apply this rule in order to create only two independent lists, what should I do?

Comment: Why are all your elements tuples?

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with equivalence classes.  Equivalence relations are transitive, so it would seem that all of the elements here of the same equivalence class?

Comment: The reason of why they are tuples, is because the function I am defining has lists of this type, this is not the original function itself, but it more or less gives away the details I am required to use in the original context of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `set` of `frozenset`s would get you roughly what you want (though it won't preserve order):

```
unique_sets = {frozenset(lst) for lst in L}
```

Though order is lost in the `set` conversion, converting back to a `list` of `list`s is fairly easy:

```
unique_lists = [list(s) for s in unique_sets]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `set` of [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset)s to get only the unique collections ignoring order and counts of items:

```
set(map(frozenset, L))
# {frozenset({'a', 'd', 'b'}), frozenset({'a', 'c', 'b'})}
```

It's then pretty trivial to convert those back to lists:

```
list(map(list, set(map(frozenset, L))))
# [['a', 'd', 'b'], ['a', 'c', 'b']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd be willing to write a `hash` method for `set` then you could do:

```
import itertools
[k for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted([set(y) for y in x], key = your_hash))]
```